# How can I filter character values in an Informix database that contain a timestamp by year and month?

Tags: informix

I use an Informix database with the version "IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10".

I have a column with char(20). We can call the column "my_example_column". All values of this column contain a timestamp.

This looks like this:

**ABC_202001171317325**

The first 4 characters "ABC_" are not relevant for me.

However, the timestamp is relevant for me. The first 4 numbers "2020" represent the year. The following 2 numbers "01" represent the month. The following 2 numbers "17" represent the day.

So the date would be January 17, 2020.

I want to filter the values in this named column "my_example_column" by year and month.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC10 we can try the following:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE my_example_table
(
    my_example_column CHAR(20)
);

-- Populate the table with 9999 rows, DBDATE env variable is set to Y4MD-
INSERT INTO my_example_table( my_example_column )
SELECT 'ABC_' || TO_CHAR( DATE( '2000-01-01' ) + ( LEVEL::CHAR(20)::INTERVAL DAY(6) TO DAY ), '%Y%m%d' ) || '0101001' AS datestring
FROM sysmaster:sysdual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10000;

-- Create an index on the column
CREATE INDEX my_example_table_idx1 ON my_example_table( my_example_column );

-- Update row distribution for the table ( create index already does this for the column )
UPDATE STATISTICS HIGH FOR TABLE my_example_table;
```

Using the substring operator to filter the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_example_table
WHERE
    my_example_column[5,8] = '2001'
AND my_example_column[9,10] = '02';
```

This query will return what we want, but it will do a sequencial scan of the table ( full table scan ), ignoring the index.

If we change the query to use the LIKE operator, we have:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_example_table
WHERE
    my_example_column LIKE 'ABC\_2001%'
AND my_example_column LIKE 'ABC\_____02%'
;
```

This query will make use of the index, but only because the 1st 4 characters are a constant ( that is the reason I am escaping the "_" on the filters ).

We can also make use of a functional index, but have not tested if it is more performant. To do that we need to define a function and use it to build the index.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_my_year( in_my_example_column CHAR( 20 ) )
RETURNING CHAR( 4 ) AS year
WITH( NOT VARIANT );

 RETURN in_my_example_column[5,8];
 
END FUNCTION;


CREATE FUNCTION get_my_month( in_my_example_column CHAR( 20 ) )
RETURNING CHAR( 2 ) AS month
WITH( NOT VARIANT );

 RETURN in_my_example_column[9,10];
 
END FUNCTION;

CREATE INDEX my_example_table_idx2 ON my_example_table( get_my_year( my_example_column ) );
CREATE INDEX my_example_table_idx3 ON my_example_table( get_my_month( my_example_column ) );
```

I used 2 functions to create 2 functional indexes ( which is probably overkill, 1 index should be enough ). Or we can create a single composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX my_example_table_idx4 ON my_example_table( get_my_year( my_example_column ), get_my_month( my_example_column ) );
```

Now we need a query that uses the functions utilized to create the indexes:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_example_table
WHERE
    get_my_year( my_example_column ) = '2001'
AND get_my_month( my_example_column ) = '02'
;
```

Using the functional indexes we can ignore the 1st 4 characters of the column ( remember, they need to be constant for the LIKE query to use the index ).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
select * 
from my_example_table
where year(to_date(my_example_column[5,12], "%Y%m%d")) = 2020
and month(to_date(my_example_column[5,12], "%Y%m%d")) = 1
```

I access the column "my_example_column" via two indexes. The index starts at 1 and not at 0. The first index is 5 and specifies the first number. In our case, the first number is 2. The second index is 12 and specifies the last number. In our case the 7th number. As a result we get 20200117.

After that I convert the string into a date with the method to_date.

`to_date(my_example_column[5,12], "%Y%m%d")`

To determine the year I use the method year:

`year(to_date(my_example_column[5,12], "%Y%m%d"))`

For the determination of the month I use the method month:

`month(to_date(my_example_column[5,12], "%Y%m%d"))`

Comment: While this will work, it isn't necessary to convert the information to a DATE value and then extract components of the date.  Doing a direct comparison of a substring with a number will work nicely too.